# Simple_form does not send value after adding columns in the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I wanted to updated a `simple_form` with more values that the user can input.

In order to do so I:

1) Create a new migrations adding in my database `questions` the new columns. The new columns apper is `schema.db`, so I assumed the new migration worked.

2) Add in the `simple_form`, the "new" `f.input` linked to the new columns.

However, once I submit the `simple_form`, the values of the new columns are not passed to the database while the old ones are passed.

**new.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

      <%= simple_form_for [@user, @project, @paper, @question], url: project_paper_questions_path do |f| %>
        <div class="form-inputs">

      <%= f.input :question_content_year, label: "1. Year"%>
      <%= f.input :question_content_country, label: "2. Country"%>
      <%= f.input :question_content_income, :collection =>[["Low income", -1], ["Middle income", 0], ["High income", 0.5]], label: "3. Income level" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_type, :collection =>[["CUA", 0], ["CEA", 1], ["CBA", 2], ["CCA", 3], ["CMA", 4]], label: "4. Type of economic evaluation" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_study, :collection =>[["RCT", 0], ["Quasi-experimental", 1], ["Modelling", 2], ["Observational", 3], ["Mixed RCT and Modelling", 4]], label: "5. Study Design " %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_modelling, :collection =>[["Decison Tree", 0], ["Markov model", 1], ["Patient level simulation/microsimulation", 2], ["Dynamic models", 3], ["Other", 4]], label: "6. Type of modeling, if modeling design " %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_perspective_a, :collection =>[["Social", 0], ["Provider/Health care system", 1], ["Program", 2], ["Patient", 3], ["Payer/Third party", 4], ["Mixed", 5]], label: "7. Perspective (as stated by authors)" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_perspective_r, :collection =>[["Social", 0], ["Provider/Health care system", 1], ["Program", 2], ["Patient", 3], ["Payer/Third party", 4], ["Mixed", 5]], label: "8. Perspective (evaluated by reviewer)" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_sensitivity, :collection =>[["One way/Univariate", 0], ["Multy-way/Multivariate", 1], ["Probabilistic analysis", 2], ["Not performaed/specified", 3], ["CMA", 4]], label: "9. Type of sensitivity analysis" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_type, :collection =>[["<= 1", 0], ["1-10 years", 1], ["Over 10 years", 2], ["Not clearly stated", 3]], label: "10. Time horizon" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_outcome, :collection =>[["QALY/DALY", 0], ["Natural units", 1], ["Process outcomes", 2], ["Monetary", 3]], label: "11. Outcome Measure" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_intervention, label: "12. Decription of Intervention/Comparison" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_data, :collection =>[["Primary", 0], ["Secondary", 1], ["Mixed", 2], ["Monetary", 3]], label: "13. Type and source of data used" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_sample, label: "14. Sample Size" %>
      <%= f.input :question_content_description, label: "15. Description of analysis outcomes" %>



      **THE FOLLOWING ARE THE OLD QUESTIONS/COLUMNS AND THEY WORK


      <%= f.input :question_1, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "1. Identify the study as an economic evaluation" %>
      <%= f.input :question_2, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "2. Provide a structured summary of objectives, methods, results and conclusions" %>
      ...
      " %>
      <%= f.input :question_28, :collection =>["N/A", "No - 0", "Partially - 0.5", "Yes - 1"], label: "24. Describe any potential for conflict of interest among study contributors in accordance with journal policy.
      " %>


      <%= f.association :user, label: "Which user is creating it?", :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id }  %>
      </div>


      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Send your review" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**schema.db**

```
  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "paper_id"
    t.bigint "project_id"
    t.string "type"
    t.string "question_1"
    t.string "question_2"
    t.string "question_3"
    t.string "question_4"
...
    t.string "question_28"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

THE FOLLOWING ARE THE COLUMNS I ADDED AND DO NOT WORK

    t.string "question_content_year"
    t.string "question_content_income"
    t.string "question_content_condensed_type"
    t.string "question_content_study"
    t.string "question_content_modelling"
    t.string "question_content_perspective_a"
    t.string "question_content_perspective_r"
    t.string "question_content_sensitivity"
    t.string "question_content_type"
    t.string "question_content_outcome"
    t.string "question_content_intervention"
    t.string "question_content_data"
    t.string "question_content_sample"
    t.string "question_content_description"
    t.string "question_content_country"
    t.index ["paper_id"], name: "index_questions_on_paper_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_questions_on_project_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_questions_on_user_id"
  end
```

**Controller**

```
  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @paper = Paper.find(params[:paper_id])
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question.project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @question.paper = Paper.find(params[:paper_id])
    if @question.save
      redirect_to projects_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Some error !"
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Only the old values (from `question_1` to `question_28` are sent to the database, while the new one - example: `:question_content_year` are not passed).
If if I check with `rails console` --> `Question.last` --> The new columns have value of `nil`.

[image: Nil value for the columns I added]
[image: The values of the new columns are not sent]

Comment: Could you please show the code of `question_params` method in your controller?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The answer below solved my issue. A very silly mistake on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have not modified the `question_params` method in your controller. You need to list the new fields in the `permit` call there.

The purpose of this permit mechanism is to whitelist attributes that you expect to be submitted with the form so that a maliciously crafted form submit can't overwrite fields that are not supposed to be updated from that form.